# DocumentDB ReplaceDocument wont save submitted subDocument

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb

The problem is: When I send a whole document and change that document in the controller, it replaces fine.
However, when i submit a subDocument and the ID of the document, fetch the document by id and add the subdocument to it, it won't replace the original document with the new.

The controller function that doens't work

```
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(string id, [FromBody]DealMutationModel mutation)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            mutation.CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;

            DealModel Deal = DealRepo.Get(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            List<DealMutationModel> mutationList = Deal.Mutations.ToList();
            DealMutationModel newMutation = mutation;
            mutationList.Add(newMutation);
            Deal.Mutations = mutationList;

            await DealRepo.UpdateDealAsync(Deal);

            return Ok();

        }

        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
```

The update function.

```
    public static async Task<Document> UpdateDealAsync(DealModel deal)
    {
        var result =  await DocumentDB.Client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(deal);
        return result;
    }
```

And the function that does work.

```
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(string id, [FromBody]DealModel deal)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DealMutationModel mutation = new DealMutationModel
            {
                UserId = CurrentUser.Id,
                Status = "matched",
                CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Note = "Deal made"
            };
            deal.Mutations = new List<DealMutationModel> { mutation };

            await DealRepo.UpdateDealAsync(deal);

            return Ok();
        }

        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
```

The sole difference that had effect was sending the whole document instead of only the mutation.
Could someone please enlighten me why? Or explain to me how it will work with just sending the mutation, cause I would like to send as little data as possible.

**Addition to the question**
In the first block of code, you can see some weird way to add the mutation to the deal. Somehow a direct: Deal.Mutations.ToList().Add(mutation); Doesn't work.
Maybe this is in relation to the problem?

**In reply to Aravind**
Can't share the whole models, but below are the top parts.
The deal model is derived from Document, the mutation model is not, as it is a part of the deal.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace BC.UI.Web.Models
{
    public class DealModel : Document
    {
       [Required]
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "createdAt")]
       public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
       ......
    }

    public class DealMutationModel
    {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
       public string Status{ get; set; }
       ......
    }
}
```

**Workaround and SDK**
The version of DocDB we use is 1.4.1, saw that 1.5.0 is out so i'll upgrade and test.
For now the workaround is creating a dynamic and fill it with the deal, use a command to get the mutation and apply that to a new mutationModel and add the mutation to the deal.

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(string id, [FromBody]MutationCommand mutationCommand)
{
    dynamic dyn = DocumentDB.Client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(DocumentDB.DealCollection.DocumentsLink).Where(d => d.Id == id).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
    var deal = (DealModel)dyn;
.....
```

Thanks in advance,
Karel

Comment: Can you please include the class definitions of DealMutationModel and DealModel? In particular, are you deriving from Document by any chance?

Comment: Edited the post with class definitions, Yes the deal model is deriving from Document.

Comment: Thanks, and forgot to ask - what's the DocumentDB SDK version?

Comment: already happy someone is responding, I've edited the post again and gave a workaround we use now.

Comment: Still would like to know a better solution so we use the webapi advantages.